# How old was Joseph when he was sold into slavery?

Tags: joseph

I have heard some debate whether he was 13 or 17 and curious about sources for this age

Answer (score 8):

**How old was Joseph when he was sold into slavery?**

**Joseph was 17 years of age.**

Genesis 37:1-3  (NASB)

Joseph’s Dream

> 1 Now Jacob lived in the land [a]where his father had sojourned, in
> the land of Canaan. 2 These are the records of the generations of
> Jacob. Joseph, **when seventeen years of age,** was pasturing the
> flock with his brothers while he was still a youth, along with the
> sons of Bilhah and the sons of Zilpah, his father’s wives. And Joseph
> brought back a bad report about them to their father. 3 Now Israel
> loved Joseph more than all his sons, because he was the son of his old
> age; and he made him a [b]varicolored tunic.

Answer (score 3):

There are several dates that give chronological information about Joseph:

- Joseph 17 when he had the first two dreams, Gen 37:2
- Joseph sold into slavery in Egypt to Potiphar, Gen 37
- Joseph works in Potiphar's house but later jailed, Gen 39
- Joseph interprets two dreams by the cupbearer and the baker, two years before Pharaoh's dreams, Gen 40, Gen 41:1.  Therefore, Joseph is 28 years old.
- Joseph 30 at the time he enters Pharaoh's service, Gen 41:46.
- Joseph supervises the collection of grain during the seven years of plenty
- Joseph meets his brothers during the second year of famine, he is presumably, 39 years old.  Gen 45:6.
- Joseph 110 years old when he dies, 50:22, 26